# Graduation from of - archaism or mistake on diploma?

Tags: grammar

My diploma certificate contains following sentence:

> Graduation from of full-time first-cycle degree programme

It obviously is a mistake, however I can't believe an official institution could make such a mistake, therefore I wanted to ask you if by any chance this is some archaic form or what ever that could explain this? I Googled "graduate from of" and nothing pops up.

To show the whole picture, it looks like this:

```
                       DIPLOMA
                       No. xxxxxx
      graduation from of full-time first-cycle degree programme
                      Name Surname

Some more details like date of birth, place of birth, subject etc.
```

Comment: That is not a "sentence" at all.  It no verb.  If there is more (before or after) then maybe we can answer whether it makes sense.

Comment: You my not have found "gratuate from of" but I did find "graduation from of" on the internet.  Those seem also to be faulty to me; but if so, why does it occur multiple places?

Comment: @GEdgar i edited the question to show how it's written. I can't find any results for "graduation from of".

Comment: Some results on "graduation from of" ... (1) https://cm.wgu.edu/t5/Teacher-Licensure-Information/NY-Certification-Requirements-and-Available-Licenses/ta-p/1091 (2) https://job-openings.monster.com/interventional-radiology-cardiac-cath-technologist-cardiac-cath-lab-richland-wa-us-kadlec/a839c11b-d6c9-43f0-ab18-fd9363ea9115 (3) https://www.bmaprop.com/team.html  [google has 28,000 matches]

Comment: "But thou, Bethlehem Ephratah, though thou be little among the thousands of Judah, yet out of thee shall he come forth unto me that is to be ruler in Israel; whose goings forth have been from of old, from everlasting."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micah_%28prophet%29

Comment: @Kris "from of old, from everlasting", here "of old" might be a reference to everlasting, as relating to the same person/object/phenomena. Not to mention using biblical form in official, academic document in 2019 is just.. unthought-of?

Comment: "Of old" is an idiom. "Of full-time" is not.

Comment: Is it that a ' / ' has been omitted? In that case it would have been 'Graduation from/of  full-time first-cycle degree programme". What occurs to me is the system of 'strike off whatever is not relevant' in which case the irrelevant one can be struck off. Just a thought, but not sure.

Comment: *"I can't believe an official institution could make such a mistake"* - Of course they could. Google "diploma typo" for more examples.

Comment: @Alex Indeed. I did think of that, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct English. I believe the intended phrase is:

> graduation from a full-time, first-cycle degree programme

Whoever wrote it misheard "a full" as "of full".

This kind of error is not uncommon when using computer dictation software.

Comment: It may also be a result of hypercorrection as 'of' tends to be spelled as 'a' in non-standard English ('cuppa milk').